# Some questions about Thread Pool in Vert.x?

Tags: multithreading, vert.x

Vert.x have many thread pool, `eventLoopGroup`,`acceptorEventLoopGroup`,`internalBlockingPool`,`workerPool`.

> Why need so many?

FileSystem read file will use `internalBlockingPool`, but like this code executeBlocking will use `workerPool`.

> And in this code why resultHandler execute in eventLoop thread not
>   workpool?

```
vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                future.complete();
            }, r -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            });
```

In my understanding eventloop just a single thread is endless loop for channel.If nothing to do with network, no need to use eventLoopGroup.

how to understand `event` in Vert.x, can give some Vert.x code not `netty` code？

Answer (score 2):

Event loops: there can be more than one event loop thread. There typically will be more than one event loop thread (it depends on your number of cores). For example,if you start N instances of a verticle, you will want it to spread across multiple cores using multiple event loops.  In the docs, look up the multi-reactor pattern.

> Vert.x works differently here. Instead of a single event loop, each
>   Vertx instance maintains several event loops. By default we choose the
>   number based on the number of available cores on the machine, but this
>   can be overridden.

http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_reactor_and_multi_reactor

Regarding your question about the result handler: The execute blocking function will run on a worker thread, but once it is all done, it will be pushed over to the event loop thread to finish the result handler.  This behavior helps with keeping certain logic on the event loop thread.

Regarding the other thread groups, they just handle specific functionality in vert.x. If you are stressed about the number of threads in vert.x, I would not worry about it. Vert.x does a good job keeping the OS threads to a minimum while maintaining high functionality and throughput.

Comment: Thanks, [ this behavior helps with keeping certain logic on the event loop thread ] can give a example？

Comment: after the execute function is finished on the worker thread, it is almost always desirable to get back on the event loop thread.  By running the result handler on the event loop, it facilitates getting back on the event-loop.  Most of your "normal" operations will be done on the event loop, the worker threads are for cases that need blocking IO or long running CPU.